# Desktop path for file output Java

Tags: java, desktop

I have this program where it will output a text file and save it in the user's computer, I wanted to save it at desktop since that's the path everyone would have.

I'm currently coding in Windows 8, which path should I use to guarantee it'll save to desktop on Windows 7??

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/Wil/Downloads/Dropbox/abc.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Receipt Saved!");
```

Comment: I never would use a program that silently saves a file onto my desktop. You simply should ask the user, where to put the file.

Comment: the path to the desktop of linux users is different than on windows

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose how can I prompt user where to save?? read my question again, I added my code there, I have no idea how to make the code look tidy here

Comment: [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
```

Comment: How can I merge mine with yours??@user1977 mine

`String content = (jLabel1.getText() + "\r\n" + N1.getText() + "\r\n" +  L1.getText()); `

`File file = new File("C:/Users/Wil/Downloads/Dropbox/abc.txt");`

Comment: Does this work for mac?